# Excel 2010 - Macro Copy range of cells instead of entire row

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried using the feedback from similar threats - but I can't seem to implement any of them in my code.
I apoligize as I'm brand new to macros!

I have a spreadsheet with a pivot table, 
from where I wish to copy A2:J2 if K2="Create".
My macro is working but is copying the entire row, can someone please help me?

```
Sub Create()
Dim RngColF As Range
Dim i As Range
Dim Dest As Range

Sheets("Data").Select
Set RngColF = Range("K1", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

With Sheets("Open quotes")
    Set Dest = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With

For Each i In RngColF
    If i.Value = "Create" Then
        i.EntireRow.Copy Dest
        Set Dest = Dest.Offset(1)
        Sheets("Open quotes").Select
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub Create()
Dim RngColF As Range
Dim i As Range
Dim Dest As Range

Sheets("Data").Select
Set RngColF = Range("K1", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

With Sheets("Open quotes")
    Set Dest = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With

For Each i In RngColF
    If i.Value = "Create" Then
        range(cells(i.row,1).address,cells(i.row,10).address).copy Dest
        Set Dest = Dest.Offset(1,0)
        Sheets("Open quotes").Select
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I am not sure where data is you want to copy. if it is in Data sheet then you will have a problem as you are selecting "Open Quotes" so the second time the runs around it will copy from "open quotes". may want to address that.

EDIT: for the sake of being complete Sheets("Open quotes").Select should (and believe OP has) be moved to the end of the code

Comment: Could you mark as answered if this has answered your question

Comment: Sorry 99moorem but could please advise on how I mark the question answered?
Your answer solved my problem and I simply moved the selection of shet Open quotes to the very end. Thank you!

Comment: to the left of my answer you should see an up and down arrow, underneath them you should see a tick greyed out, click that to mark this as the answer that answered your questions :)